# Oracle SQL query that will remove duplicates using a substring, and link the list of deduped records to another table

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, substring

**Example table data**

```
|TAB    | MODDATE    |ORDERID  |
|-------| ---------  |---------|
|TableOH| 01/11/2021 |811911|
|TableOH| 01/11/2021 |811913|
|TableOH| 01/11/2021 |260854|
|TableOL| 01/11/2021 |260854#10|
|TableOH| 01/11/2021 |379452|
|TableOL| 01/11/2021 |379452#10|
|TableOL| 01/11/2021 |379452#20|
|TableOL| 01/11/2021 |379452#10|
|TableOL| 01/11/2021 |379452#20|
|TableOH| 01/11/2021 |379452|
|TableOH| 01/11/2021 |379453|
|TableOL| 01/11/2021 |379453#10|
|TableOL| 01/11/2021 |379453#10|
|TableOH| 01/11/2021 |379453|
```

**Desired result.**

```
|TAB    | MODDATE    |ORDERID  |
|-------| ---------  |---------|
|TableOH| 01/11/2021 |  811911|
|TableOH| 01/11/2021 |811913|
|TableOL| 01/11/2021 |260854|
|TableOH|  01/11/2021 |379452|
|TableOH|  01/11/2021 |379453|
```

Example Query  (finds all records and links the tables)

```
SELECT 
"DATABASE"."DUPTABLE"."TAB",
"DATABASE"."DUPTABLE"."MODDATE",
SUBSTR( “DATABASE”.”DUPTABLE”."ORDERID",1,6),
" DATABASE"."ORDERHEADER"."ORNO",
" DATABASE"."ORDERHEADER"."CUSTNO",

FROM "DATABASE"."DUPTABLE", "DATABASE"."ORDERHEADER"


WHERE 

“DATABASE”.”DUPTABLE”."MODDATE " > DATE ' 2021-01-11' AND  “DATABASE”.”DUPTABLE”." MODDATE " < DATE ' 2021-01-11'
 AND (“DATABASE”.”DUPTABLE”." TAB" = 'TableOH' OR “DATABASE”.”DUPTABLE”."TAB" = 'TableOL')  
AND SUBSTR(“DATABASE”.”DUPTABLE”."ORDERID",1,6) = "DATABASE"."ORDERHEADER"."ORNO"
```

I am trying to figure out a way to select the records in the "desired result" table, and link these records to the "ORDERHEADER" table.
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
MS

Comment: I think you just need to do a `select distinct` in your query to get your desired result. What do you mean by linking the records to the order header table?

Comment: `“DATABASE”.”DUPTABLE”."MODDATE " > DATE ' 2021-01-11' AND  “DATABASE”.”DUPTABLE”." MODDATE " < DATE ' 2021-01-11'` will always return false.

Comment: Hi Andrew,  the deduped results are used to find the records in the order table.

Comment: Popeye -  not sure why but I had to  MODDATE " < DATE ' 2021-01-11' to return results. but that is another problem :)

Comment: when using the select distinct is there a way to display the data from other columns?

e.g

SELECT 
DISTINCT SUBSTR( “DATABASE”.”DUPTABLE”."ORDERID",1,6),

Show column data ......
"DATABASE"."DUPTABLE"."TAB",
"DATABASE"."DUPTABLE"."MODDATE",
" DATABASE"."ORDERHEADER"."ORNO",
" DATABASE"."ORDERHEADER"."CUSTNO",